# Wakanda mobile app development using Page Prototype

Tags: mobile, build, wakanda

I am trying to develop a mobile app on Wakanda v11 starting with prototyping my page,test run it and try to build the prototyped page into an .apk file but all the system does is building the sample application in the mobile folder.
Any suggestion as how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a mobile app you must create it in the mobile folder in Wakanda Studio.

Today, there is no prototyping tool inside Wakanda to do a mobile app.

But you can use ionic creator to prototype your mobile app. When you have done that, you could integrate it in the Wakanda mobile folder.

There is a tutorial that can help you here : [tutorial to create a first mobile app with Wakanda](http://nscurious.com/2016/03/02/how-to-create-your-first-mobile-app-for-ios-and-android-with-a-real-backend/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a native mobile application so you can generate the .apk, you should use Ionic/Cordova/Angular, by developing you application in the 'mobile' folder. you can follow the example set by default.
To access to database you can use the Angular/Wakanda connector : [Docs](http://wakanda.github.io/angular-wakanda/#/doc/developer-guide)
The prototype application cannot generate an .apk file

Comment: It's really a let down that Wakanda hasn't come up with the capability to develop end-to-end applications where the users can access backend data while enjoying some native mobile functions.   But thanks for the answers.